# Gradle issue with Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools, android-studio-2.3

I am getting the following error: 
"

> The SDK platform tools version (25.0.6) is too old to check APIs
>   compiled with API 26; please update This check scans through all
>   ANDroid API calls in the application and  warns about any calls that
>   are not available on all versions targeted by the application
>   (according to its minimum SDK attribute in the manifest). If you
>   really want to use this API and don’t need to support older devices
>   just set the minSdkVersion in the build.gradle or AndroidManifest.xml
>   files If your code is deliberately accessing newer APIs and you have
>   ensured (e.g. with conditional execution) that this code will only
>   ever be called on a supported platform, then you can annotate you
>   class or method with the @TargetApi annotation specifying the local
>   minimum SDK to Apply, such as @TargetApi(11), such that this check
>   considers 11 rather than you manifest file’s minimum SDK as the
>   required API level.   If you are deliberately setting android:
>   attributes in style definitions, make sure you place this in
>   values-xxx folder in order to avoid running into runtime conflicts on
>   certain devices where manufacturers have added custom attributes whose
>   ids conflict with new ones or later platforms. Similarly, you can use
>   tooltargetApi=”11” in an XML file to indicate that the elements will
>   only be inflated in an adequate context."

I also get the package name up top as an error, but I just created the new App and even though it indicates an error. The source code compiles and runs on the emulator on the targeted device.

Comment: Did you first read the error message and suggested fix before posting here?

Comment: step1. read error message

Comment: step2. fix. maybe its working

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) Also, error messages have words in them that are there for a reason other than to take up screen space. Read those words, and pay attention to what they say.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your App Level Gradle file and enter the following:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId ">>>YOURPACKAGENAME<<<"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
```